# Errors when using parseCpp to parse C++ files

Tags: rascal

I am trying to use Clair and Rascal to analyze C++ files.

I followed the instructions on the Github page of Clair to add Clair to an empty Rascal project. After importing the required modules successfuly, I attempted to call `parseCpp` to parse a C++ file and got the following errors:

```
rascal>parseCpp(|project://myproject3/myFile.cpp|);
|jar+file:///Users/rh07/.m2/repository/org/rascalmpl/clair/0.4.0/clair-0.4.0.jar!/src/lang/cpp/AST.rsc|(24317,206,<455,0>,<456,167>): Java("NoSuchMethodError","\'io.usethesource.vallang.IString org.rascalmpl.library.Prelude.readFile(io.usethesource.vallang.ISourceLocation)\'")
        at lang.cpp.internal.CDTParser.parseFileAsCpp(|unknown:///CDTParser.java|(0,0,<202,0>,<202,0>))
        at lang.cpp.internal.Parser.parseCpp(|unknown:///Parser.java|(0,0,<349,0>,<349,0>))
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(|unknown:///NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java|(0,0,<0,0>,<0,0>))
        at parseCpp(|jar+file:///Users/rh07/.m2/repository/org/rascalmpl/clair/0.4.0/clair-0.4.0.jar!/src/lang/cpp/AST.rsc|(24516,5,<456,160>,<456,165>)Beginning at 2022-11-25T11:35:54.827391Z
WARNING: ResourcesPlugin was null, can't get workspace; not overriding include files
```

How I can get `parseCpp` to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a bad combination of versions. Please use `clair-0.5.0` (just released) which will work with rascal-0.27.2 that is distributed with the Rascal VScode extension 0.5.5.

Adopt the pom.xml like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.rascalmpl</groupId>
  <artifactId>clair</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @RH07 there is also a new VScode extension coming up: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/issues/204 which will make using a library much easier.